# Slidein new activity in android app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, slide

I have this piece of code to start a new activity in my android test app

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Button btnpriv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_priv);
   btnpriv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrivateActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);
      }
});
```

This works as it should. At button press it changes to the new PrivateActivity. But it is a  no-animation change. How can I make it f.x. slidein the new activity to have a nice transition?